# Laravel 5 setting route parameter from middleware

Tags: laravel, parameters, laravel-5, middleware, slug

The problem: I'd like to resolve slugs, if a slug has been used as a route parameter instead of an id.

Attempted Solution:
I'm currently getting a parameter from the request in my middleware and trying to set it back to the request. But it seems that this isn't passed to the route (it is passed to subsequent middleware)

Route:

```
Route::get('view_events/{gid}', array('as' => 'view_events','middleware' => ['auth','resolveGroupSlug','groupAdmin'], function($gid) 
{
    $user = Auth::user();
    $group = Team::find($gid);
    echo $gid;
      //get this user's relationship to group
    $group["team_user"] = Users_team::findComposite($gid,$user["id"]);
    $events = Helpers::getEvents($gid,0);
    return View::make('view_events', array('user' => $user, 'group' => $group, 'events' => $events));
}));
```

Middleware (resolveGroupSlug):

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        //convert a string gid to id number
        if (is_string ($request->gid)) {
            $group = Team::where('slug', '=', $request->gid)->firstOrFail();
            $request['gid'] = $group->id;
            echo $request->gid;
        }
        return $next($request);
    }
```

Any ideas how to set a route parameter in middleware? Or if there is just an easier way of doing this.

(No, i'm not going to copy paste the middleware code into every route i need this in!)

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

The new value wont get passed as a parameter in the route closure. 
You need to get it from `$request->request->get('gid');`
Try `dd($gid, $request->request->get('gid')); and compare.` 
Or `$request->gid` will proxy to the same methodcall

Comment: That's true, but would mean that i'd have to have a line of code in every route to replace `$gid` with `$request->gid`. I think i may have found a better way though

Answer (score 1):

In the end, i didn't use middlewhere, but instead bound a function to routes that have gid as follows

```
Route::bind('gid', function($gid)
{
    $group = Team::where('slug', '=', $gid)->orWhere('id', '=', $gid)->first();
    $gid = $group->id;
    return $gid;
});
```

This means that all existing code will continue to work, whether people are linking via ids or slugs.

Any feedback, i'd love to know if i'm doing something silly here?

Obviously i'm now aware that i could be passing the group directly to the controller, but some of my controllers are only after the id, not the whole group, so this gives me the best flexibility.

Comment: If you need to access this parameter from e.g. middleware:

`Route::getCurrentRoute()->parameters();`

Comment: If you try that, you'll get null. As the current route hasn't actually been set yet. Did try that one.

Comment: Where you defining those route binds? I've used the route parameter in a middleware before without issues. I define the route binds in `App\Providers\RouteProvider`